# steampy. Always getting TooManyRequests

Tags: python, discord.py, steam-web-api

Today i started making Discord bot that will track market price of my CS:GO Stickers. Problem is when I trying to fetch market price using steampy I always getting TooManyRequests error.

This fragment of a code.

```
@client.command()
async def cena(ctx):   
    global steam_client
    f = open('items.json', "r")
    data = json.load(f)
    item_dict = data['items_info']
    for x in item_dict:
        item = x['item']
        quantity = x['quantity']
        cost = x['cost']
        market = steam_client.market.fetch_price(item, game=GameOptions.CS, currency=Currency.EURO)
        print(market)
        if  market == None or market['success'] == False:
            await ctx.send("error") 
            break
        else:      
            lowest = market['lowest_price'].replace("€", "").replace(",", ".")
            ans = f"{item} : **{lowest}€** ||{cost}€ ({quantity})||"
            await ctx.send(ans)
    f.close()
    time.sleep(6)
```

Here is items.json

```
{
        "items_info" : [
        { 
            "item" : "Sticker | Spirit (Holo) | 2020 RMR",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "cost" : 0.50,
            "sellat" : 0.65
        },
        {
            "item" : "Sticker | Virtus.pro (Holo) | 2020 RMR",
            "quantity" : 1,
            "cost" : 0.61,
            "sellat" : 0.90
        },
        { 
            "item" : "Sticker | FURIA (Holo) | 2020 RMR",
            "quantity" : 2,
            "cost" : 0.48,
            "sellat" : 0.60
        },
        { 
            "item" : "Sticker | Renegades (Holo) | 2020 RMR",
            "quantity" : 5,
            "cost" : 0.20,
            "sellat" : 0.30
        }
       ]
}
```

I tried to revoking my Steam API Key it didn't help. I've also tried with another packages like steammarket but it didn't work too. It happends even in first fetch.

EDIT I tried run code today and first time it fetched cost of first two sticker but in sticker three it stopped working at all.

Comment: I've ran into the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You exceed the rate limit imposed by the Steam API, you gonna have to add a delay in between the request you make.
The best would be to use `asyncio.sleep` to add delay.

```
import asyncio

@client.command()
async def cena(ctx):   
    global steam_client
    f = open('items.json', "r")
    data = json.load(f)
    item_dict = data['items_info']
    for x in item_dict:
        item = x['item']
        quantity = x['quantity']
        cost = x['cost']
        market = steam_client.market.fetch_price(item, game=GameOptions.CS, currency=Currency.EURO)
        print(market)
        if  market == None or market['success'] == False:
            await ctx.send("error") 
            break
        else:      
            lowest = market['lowest_price'].replace("€", "").replace(",", ".")
            ans = f"{item} : **{lowest}€** ||{cost}€ ({quantity})||"
            await ctx.send(ans)
        
        # Add a delay between requests
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

    f.close()
```

Comment: Didn't work. Still same error

Comment: I modified my code with a bigger delay maybe it will work

Comment: It happening on first fetch.